# Storing a value of function

Tags: sql, oracle11g, stored-functions

I have a SQL query in which I am calculating a function cal(a,b) and performing subtraction like below

```
case
when a=1 and b=0 then case when (c -cal(a,b)) >0 then cal(a,b) else c end
end
```

In such a scenario, I have to call cal(a,b) twice which is costly.

Is there any way in oracle SQL such that I can store the value of this function
and it is pre-written SQL query so I can not use PL/SQL.

Comment: Is the function designated as deterministic?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you use your mentionned statement, you can have a table that stores such result, a new column that stores such result, in both cases, the values are either calculated "on demand", or calculated using a trigger. It may also be a materialized view that store such result of cal(a, b), but again, it depends how easy it is to obtain a and b, process and store, but also retrieve the result.

That being said, Oracle caching system is well-done and I'm not sure why Oracle would process cal(a, b) a second time if it was called with the same parameter in the same statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (case when a = 1 and b = 10and c > cal_11
             then cal_11
        end)
from (select t.*, 
             (case when a = 1 and b = 0 then cal(a, b) end) as cal11
      from t
     ) t;
```